# JVM and main thread are still running after System.exit()

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I need to shut down the application completely after ThreadPoolExecutor completes the currently executing tasks.For this I added the below code:

```
private void stopAppGracefully()
{
    MyApplication.executor.shutdown();

    System.exit(0);

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
      public void run() {

        logger.debug("Called the addShutdownHook()");

        //Wait infinitely till executor shut down
        while(!MyApplication.executor.isTerminated())
        {
          continue;
        }

        int queued = MyApplication.executor.getQueue().size();
        int active = MyApplication.executor.getActiveCount();
        int notCompleted = queued + active; // approximate

        long submitted = MyApplication.executor.getTaskCount();
        long completed = MyApplication.executor.getCompletedTaskCount();
        long notCompleted2 = submitted - completed; // approximate

        logger.debug("App is down..queued...:"+queued);
        logger.debug("App is down..active...:"+active);
        logger.debug("App is down..queued + active...:"+notCompleted);

        logger.debug("App is down..submitted...:"+submitted);
        logger.debug("App  is down..completed...:"+completed);
        logger.debug("App is down..submitted - completed...:"+notCompleted2);

        System.gc();

        Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
        Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);

        for (int i = 0; i < threadArray.length; i++)
        {
          logger.debug("Remaining threads: "+ threadArray[i].getName());
        }
      }
    });
}
```

But I see the below information in logs:

```
20 Jul 2017 05:03:17 DEBUG | ApplicationDirectoryWatcher | run | 292 - App is down..queued...:0
20 Jul 2017 05:03:17 DEBUG | ApplicationDirectoryWatcher | run | 293 - App is down..active...:0
20 Jul 2017 05:03:17 DEBUG | ApplicationDirectoryWatcher | run | 294 - App is down..queued + active...:0
20 Jul 2017 05:03:17 DEBUG | ApplicationDirectoryWatcher | run | 296 - App is down..submitted...:43
20 Jul 2017 05:03:17 DEBUG | ApplicationDirectoryWatcher | run | 297 - App is down..completed...:43
20 Jul 2017 05:03:17 DEBUG | ApplicationDirectoryWatcher | run | 298 - App is down..submitted - completed...:0
20 Jul 2017 05:03:17 DEBUG | ApplicationDirectoryWatcher | run | 307 - Remaining threads: Finalizer
20 Jul 2017 05:03:17 DEBUG | ApplicationDirectoryWatcher | run | 307 - Remaining threads: Reference Handler
20 Jul 2017 05:03:17 DEBUG | ApplicationDirectoryWatcher | run | 307 - Remaining threads: Thread-3
20 Jul 2017 05:03:17 DEBUG | ApplicationDirectoryWatcher | run | 307 - Remaining threads: Thread-2
20 Jul 2017 05:03:17 DEBUG | ApplicationDirectoryWatcher | run | 307 - Remaining threads: Thread-1
20 Jul 2017 05:03:17 DEBUG | ApplicationDirectoryWatcher | run | 307 - Remaining threads: main
20 Jul 2017 05:03:17 DEBUG | ApplicationDirectoryWatcher | run | 307 - Remaining threads: Signal Dispatcher
```

Still seven threads are active.
How to kill/stop these threads ?

I need to stop/kill all the threads belonging to the application.

Comment: Why do you care that some threads are still active at that point? What actual problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @Kenster the problem might be port occupancy

Answer (score 2):

[`ExecutorService.shutdown()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) does not immediately kill all running tasks and stop all threads. It will continue to run the tasks that are currently running. Note that `shutdown()` doesn't wait - it immediately returns, and current tasks may at that point still be running.

You can call [`awaitTermination(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) to wait for the currently running tasks to finish, or [`shutdownNow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--) which does indeed attempt to kill all currently running tasks.

To attempt to shutdown an `ExecutorService` gracefully, and then forcefully if it doesn't stop within a certain amount of time, you can use the following:

```
// Initiate graceful shutdown
executorService.shutdown();

try {
    // Wait one minute for tasks to finish
    boolean terminated = executorService.awaitTermination(1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    if (!terminated) {
        // If not terminated after one minute, shutdown forcefully
        executorService.shutdownNow();
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.err.println("Interrupted while awaiting termination");
}
```

Comment: was not aware of shutdownNow() plus for that

Comment: @Jesper : I am more concerned about the threads like Finalizer,Reference Handler,Thread-3,Thread-2,Thread-1,main,Signal Dispatcher. They are still running.

Comment: Thread-1, -2, -3 are most likely threads that your `ExecutorService` created, which are still executing tasks that were submitted to it.

Comment: @Jesper : Is there any way to stop forcefully all these seven threads ?

Comment: Don't know. It's weird that code after the statement `System.exit(0);` is executed at all. That method [never returns normally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit-int-) according to the API docs so any statements after that should never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can use `kill -9` with PID. On Windows, go to task manager and `end task`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the Java documentation we see that the `System.exit( int )` method basically does the same work as manually calling the `Runtime.getRuntime().exit( int )` method. Then again, have a look at the Java documentation of the `addShutdownHook( Thread )` method. Quoting that:

> Once the shutdown sequence has begun it is impossible to register a new shutdown hook or de-register a previously-registered hook. Attempting either of these operations will cause an IllegalStateException to be thrown.

Having read this, you probably have a synchronization error, in which the VM starts preparing the halting phase when the `System.exit( int )` method is executed, but then, before the actual shutdown sequence starts, the `addShutdownHook( Thread )` line is executed. The result is that it tells you there are threads running because effectively, they are, since the VM hasn't completely shut down yet.